# How to make a circular shift twice using an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a program that will shift the the array in this code by two, For example, a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4} and output {3,4,0,1,2} I wrote code already, but I'm missing something.. Appreciate any help!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void circularShift(int a[], int size)
{

    for (int i = size-2; i >=0; i--)
    {
        int temp = a[i+1];
        a[i+1] = a[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    int size = 5;

    circularShift(a, 5);

    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i]<< " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that! Fixed it

Comment: `std::rotate()` is your choice.

Comment: How would I be able to do it just using the indices?

Comment: You assign something to `temp`, but then you never use it.

Comment: Do you have an idea of an algorithm, a way you want `circularShift` to work?

Comment: I was thinking of adding "a[0] = temp" right after a[i+1] = a[i]" but that still didn't work

Comment: I thought about taking the last element and then inserting it into temp and then shift everything and finally place the value in temp into a[0]

Comment: That last idea will work (if you carry it out twice), but you can't just guess commands like "a[0] = temp" and expect the whole to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void circularShift(int a[], int size)
{
    int tmp1 = a[size - 1];
    int tmp2 = a[size - 2];
    for (int i = size-3; i >=0; i--)
    {
        a[i+2] = a[i];
    }
    a[1] = tmp1;
    a[0] = tmp2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
void circularShift(int a[], int size)
{
    assert(size >= 2);
    std::rotate(a, a + size - 2, a + size);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Zd3hu4)

Comment: It would be neat to link to the documentation about [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
void circularShift(int a[], int size)
{
   int tmp = a[0];
   for (int i = 0; i < size-1 ; i++)
   {
       a[i]=a[i+1];
   }
   a[size-1] = tmp; 
}
```

Comment: OP explicitly mentioned `circular shift twice`

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not right:

1. It accesses `a[5]` in the 1st iteration
2. If you need to shift right twice then you need to calculate the new indexes for the elements:

   `newIndex = (oldIndex+2)%5`

   It will make sure you have a circular shift in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is high complexity method but it still works for your problem.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void circularShift(int a[], int size)
{
    int no;
    int rotate_no = 2;
    for(int j=0; j<rotate_no; j++)
    {
        no = a[size-1];
        for (int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
        {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = no;
            no = temp;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    int size = 5;

    circularShift(a, 5);

    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i]<< " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
void circularShift(int a[], int size, int rotations)
{
  int temp = a[0];
  for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
  {
      int temp1 = a[((i+1)*rotations)%size];
      a[((i+1)*rotations)%size] = temp;
      temp = temp1;
  }
}
```